# Why working observe_field code doesn't work with JQuery Model dialog box?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm developing a project on rails and I got a problem on getting the selected item on drop down menu. It works fine on views/applications but when I try to use the same code to get the selected item at the jQuery model dialog box, it doesn't work for me. Can someone explain the problem in this? Can't I use the observe_field on model dialog box?

This is my code:

```
        <%= label_tag :Search_by %>
         <select name="search" id="search" >
            <option value="0">Name</option>
            <option value="1">Trainer</option>
            <option value="2">Venue</option>
            <option value="3">Date</option>
         </select>

        <div id="div_to_be_updated" style="float:right">
            <%= render 'layouts/new_search' %>
        </div>

            <%= observe_field 'search', :update => 'div_to_be_updated',
            :url => {:controller => 'events', :action=> 'find' },
            :with => "'is_delivery_address=' + escape(value)" %>                 
        </div>
```

This is my "find" method in "events" controller:

```
enter code here
def find
@trainers= Trainer.all
@countries= Country.all

        if ["0"].include?(params[:is_delivery_address])
            render :partial => 'layouts/new_search'
        else if ["2"].include?(params[:is_delivery_address])
            render :partial => 'layouts/venu_search'
        else if ["1"].include?(params[:is_delivery_address])
            render :partial => 'layouts/trainer_search'
        else
            # check element is date range...
            render :partial => 'layouts/date_search'

        end
        end
    end
end
```

I can't understand the reason for this problem. It works in application.html.erb file but it doesn't work on the jQuery model dialog box.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. However, it sounds like you *may* be looking for jQuery's `live()` function. It allows you to observe dynamically generated DOM objects (such as dialog boxes).

Comment: I just need to know how to use observe a dropdown menu on Jquery model dialog box. I have added working code for the observe filed but it doesn't work on Model dialog box. So I need to know how to do this ?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem still working on this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field) that RoR uses Prototype to create 'observable' element in form. If this happens before you create your jQuery **modal** dialog box (i guess again you use jQuery UI Dialog) it could 'observe' wrong or non existing element.

Try creating dialog before observable ergo before RoRs PrototypeHelpers run.